# How I can properly bind the array to the angular input model attribute?

Tags: angular, angular-material

### I am trying to add and delete items to a Angular material(angular 4+material beta) table using `html <md-list>`

The issue is the two binding from .ts to html for the array (purchaseInvoiceStockItemList) is not showing the right items.

This case happens when I delete one of the array element. The HTML interpolation array data is correct, however the binding of the array item to the  input model is incorrect. 
Can someone point to what I am missing?

This is the array that show correct values after deleting

```html
<div>{{purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList | json}}</div>
```

But once I iterate through the array, **I don't get to see the *item correct values** ..

```html
 <md-list>
          <ng-template
            let-index="index"
            let-item
            let-last="last"
            ngFor
            [ngForOf]="purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList"
          >
            <md-list-item
              layout="row"
              layout-wrap
              (click)="selectLineItem(item, index)"
            >
              <span
                class="invoice-form-list-item-index"
                flex="10"
                class="padding-side"
              >
                {{ index + 1 }}</span
              >

              <span flex="40" class="padding-side">
                <md-input-container style="margin-top: -4px !important;">
                  <input
                    mdInput
                    placeholder="Choose Stock Item"
                    [(ngModel)]="item.stockItem.productName"
                    (focus)="filterStockItems($event.target.values)"
                    (keyup)="filterStockItems($event.target.value)"
                    [mdAutocomplete]="autoStockItems"
                    [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
                    [readOnly]="isEditable == 'false'"
                  />
                  <md-autocomplete #autoStockItems="mdAutocomplete">
                    <md-option
                      *ngFor="let fitem of filteredStockItems"
                      (click)="selectStockItem(fitem)"
                    >
                      {{ fitem.productName }}
                    </md-option>
                  </md-autocomplete>
                </md-input-container>
              </span>
              <span flex="15" class="padding-side">
                <md-input-container style="margin-top: -4px !important;">
                  <input
                    mdInput
                    type="number"
                    [(ngModel)]="item.qty"
                    (change)="itemValueChange(item)"
                    [readOnly]="isEditable == 'false'"
                  />
                </md-input-container>
              </span>
              <span flex="15" class="padding-side">
                <md-input-container style="margin-top: -4px !important;">
                  <input
                    mdInput
                    type="number"
                    [(ngModel)]="item.rate"
                    (change)="itemValueChange(item)"
                    [readOnly]="isEditable == 'false'"
                  />
                </md-input-container>
              </span>
              <span flex="15" class="padding-side">
                {{ item.itemTotal | amount }}
              </span>
              <span
                flex="5"
                style="cursor: pointer;text-align:right;"
                class="padding-side"
                *ngIf="isEditable == 'true'"
              >
                <md-icon color="accent" (click)="removeItem(index)"
                  >delete</md-icon
                >
              </span>
            </md-list-item>
          </ng-template>
        </md-list>
```

**Typescript**

```js
  filterStockItems(val: string) {
    if (this.isEditable == "true") {
      this.filteredStockItems =
        val && val != ""
          ? this.stockItemList.filter(
              s => s.productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            )
          : this.stockItemList;
    } else {
      this.filteredStockItems = [];
    }
  }

   addStockItem() {
    if (
      this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList.length == 0 ||
      this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList[
        this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList.length - 1
      ].stockItem.id != null
    ) {
      let item = new PurchaseInvoiceItem();
      item.id = null;
      item.qty = 1;
      item.itemTotal = 0.0;
      item.taxInclusive = "true";
      this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList.push(item);
    }
  }

  selectLineItem(lineItem, index) {
    if (this.itemSelected !== lineItem) {
      this.itemSelected = lineItem;
    }
  }

  selectStockItem(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    this.itemSelected.stockItem.id = item.id;
    this.itemSelected.taxInclusive = "false";
    this.itemSelected.stockItem.productName = item.productName;
    this.itemSelected.rate = item.costPrice;
    this.itemCalculate(this.itemSelected);
    this.addStockItem();
    this.calculateTotal();
  }

  itemValueChange(item: any) {
    this.itemCalculate(item);
    this.calculateTotal();
  }

  itemCalculate(item: any) {
    item.itemTotal = item.qty * item.rate;
  }

  calculateTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList.forEach(element => {
      let qty = element.qty;
      let price = element.rate != null ? element.rate : 0.0;
      console.log(element);
      total += qty * price;
    });
    this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseSubTotal = total;
    this.purchaseInvoice.totalPurchaseAmount =
      total + this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseTaxAmount;
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    if (this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceStockItemList.splice(index, 1);
        this.calculateTotal();
      }, 10);
    }
  }
```

Appreciate all the help here ..

Comment: Please show the definition for `filterStockItems()`, `filteredStockItems` and all related code.

Comment: Added the code from html and typescript.